Who should post the answer?
A user posted the following question: Sulla pronuncia del nome Elena . Three users (including myself) posted a series of comments, which basically answer the question in the same way.
OP has thanked the three of us, asking to post an answer. Which one of us should answer?

Probabilmente il punto è che, come spesso accade, le risposte sono date direttamente come commento, altrimenti il problema non verrebbe fuori per niente. In alcune parti di SE la cosa non è vista molto bene, qui sono meno pignoli.

In my opinion, this is not a problem. You or any other user can post an answer to this or to any other question in the site. The fact of having some comments written by some specific users shouldn't be a problem or a barrier: anyone can answer!

Who should post an answer? The first one to post an answer.
Comments are not unhelpful, but they are "second best" on SE sites. First of all, they are likely to get deleted eventually. An answer won't, unless it is really bad, or "spam." Second of all, an answer can be upvoted (or downvoted) a comment can't (except in extreme cases connected with "flagging). Basically, an answer represents content for the site, and meets the sites objectives.
So don't be shy, if you have something to say, say it. If you feel that one of the other posters knows the subject better, you might say so and let him or her have the first crack. But if s/he doesn't, you should step into the breach. 
In my family, for instance, my sister is by far the better pianist. But I am the one who plays the piano in public.
